# Readings about Perron Frobenius theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

For the third point in the following picture, [image]

I feel like the statement is false:

Because Let $N=[v_1,..,v_n]$ where $v_i \in \mathcal{R}^n$ are column vectors such that $v_i=\mathbf{1} \forall i \neq j$ and $v_j=\mathbf{0}$

let $z=e_j$, then $Nz=\mathbf{0}$ but $N \neq \mathbf{0}$

Comment: Your $z$ isn't positive.

Comment: Frobenius, not Drobinius.